# Flutter: Grid View in drawer

Tags: gridview, dart, flutter, drawer

I want to display a grid of menus in the drawer but got stuck

When using GridView.count in page then its working and if the same is used inside a drawer then it is showing some rendering problem

```
Scaffold scaffold = Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('X'),
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(
      child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: Text('X'),
        accountEmail: Text('x@gmail.com'),
        currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          child: Text(
            'X',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('A')
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )),
);
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the GridView's shrinkWrap property to true.

```
GridView.count(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('A'),
  ],
),
```

This constrains the widgets height to only what is required.